# Removing 'FALSE' and 'NAs' from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, subset

I want to remove 'FALSE' and 'NAs' from a large dataframe. My input looks like,

| ID | Codes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 2 | NA |
| 3 | FALSE |
| 4 | TRUE |

My required output is,

| ID | Codes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 4 | TRUE |

Please suggest the best way to do it in R
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `subset` and specify `Codes` (assuming that it is logical column, the `NA` will be dropped)

```
subset(df1, Codes)
  ID Codes
1  1  TRUE
4  4  TRUE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Codes = c(TRUE, NA, FALSE, TRUE)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `Codes` are of type character:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Codes == "TRUE")
```

If they are logical:

```
df %>%
  filter(Codes)
```

Comment: The second case doesn't even need the `== TRUE` part.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: But, to be honest, using `== TRUE` makes it easier to read/understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R approach: Using `complete.cases`

```
df1$Codes[df1$Codes == FALSE] <- NA
df1[complete.cases(df1),]
```

output:

```
  ID Codes
1  1  TRUE
4  4  TRUE
```

Comment: Or `df1[df1$Codes & !is.na(df1$Codes),]`.